# How to change order increment prefix?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, store-view, ce-1.9.1.0, increment-id

I run a shop (Magento CE 1.6.2) with 4 different store-views, which have (for historical reasons) ID's 1, 3, 4 and 7. Order numbers have been looking like this 10000001, 30000001, 40000001, 70000001.

I have set-up a brand new install with Magento CE 1.9.1, but now the store-ID's are 1, 2, 3, 4...

How do I change this in the old situation?

I came across this post --> http://www.thevortexcode.com/how-to-change-order-prefix-and-default-value-of-ordershipmentinvoice-numbercredit-memo-in-magento/ explaining how to set/cahnge the `eav_entity_store.increment_prefix`

But this does not seem to work in 1.9...

Comment: In case if you want to try https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just edit the ID of the stores in the `store_id` column in the `core_store` database table. Because of the foreign keys, this will get updated in almost all of the other tables.

Additionally you should update:

- `default_store_id` column in `core_store_group` table

---

As commented, changing your actual database ID's would be a bit radical. Also you would still have to update the `eav_entity_store` table.

So ,you could also simply set a per store configuration for your increment ID's. You can do this in the `eav_entity_store` table:

- For store ID 1, set `increment_prefix` to 1
- For store ID 2, set `increment_prefix` to 3
- For store ID 3, set `increment_prefix` to 4
- For store ID 4, set `increment_prefix` to 7

Comment: if OP just want's to change the order increment ID wouldn't this be a bit radical for that? Better change the prefix of the increment IDs

Comment: Thanks, very simple after all... I was afraid to mess stuff up, but you can actually set prefix and order ID just altering this one table.

Comment: Here i have 2 stores, store 1 by default order increment prefix start with 10000, how can i change to store 2 like order increment prefix 30000.

Answer (score 4):

Better use model wrappers rather than raw sql statements.

**Example:**

```
$productEntityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')
    ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY);
$entityStoreConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')
    ->loadByEntityStore($productEntityType->getId(), 0);
$entityStoreConfig->setEntityTypeId($productEntityType->getId())
    ->setStoreId(0)
    ->setIncrementPrefix($prefix)
    ->setIncrementLastId($lastId)
    ->save();
```

**See:**

- https://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/12/magento-tutorial-use-increment-models-generate-ids-or-skus/
- https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-order-and-customer-numbers/

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this many times for different reasons and this is what I do:

This query will show you the increment id only for entity_type_code = order

```
SELECT * FROM  eav_entity_store join eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order';
```

Once you located the rows you would like to update you can change them like this:

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
INNER JOIN eav_entity_type ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET eav_entity_store.increment_prefix='X'
WHERE eav_entity_type.entity_type_code='order' and eav_entity_store.eav_entity_store_id = {row_id_here};
```

**Notice that the value for increment_last_id already contains the increment_prefix, so I usually removed the old increment_prefix from increment_last_id so the new orders increment id looks good.**

If you have **quotes with a reserved increment_order_id then is possible that you will still see orders with the old increment_id**. Once you start generating new quotes after the update all should be fine.

Usually in my development environment I just set all the quotes to **is_active = 0** after updating the increment_id just to have a fresh start.

For more details check here: http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Answer (score 2):

I really try and avoid direct queries into a magento db. If possible, create a simple module that has an install or upgrade script which will do this for you. For example, you can use the below script to change the increment id and increment prefix:

```
<?php

    $this->startSetup();

    /*
     * Get the resource model
    */
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /*
    * Retrieve the write connection
    */
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

   /*
    * Retrieve our table name
    */
    $table = $resource->getTableName('eav/entity_store');

    $table2=$resource->getTableName('eav/entity_type');


    $query = "UPDATE {$table}
    INNER JOIN {$table2} ON {$table2}.entity_type_id ={$table}.entity_type_id
    SET {$table}.increment_last_id='XXXXXXXXX'
    WHERE {$table2}.entity_type_code='order' AND eav_entity_store.store_id = 'Y'";

   /*
   * Execute the query
   */
   $writeConnection->query($query);

   $this->endSetup();
```

Where XXXXXXXXX is your increment id you want to start at and Y being the store id you want to do this for.

To change the actual prefix, use the query below:

```
        $query = "UPDATE {$table}
    INNER JOIN {$table2} ON {$table2}.entity_type_id ={$table}.entity_type_id
    SET {$table}.increment_prefix='X'
    WHERE {$table2}.entity_type_code='order' AND eav_entity_store.store_id = 'Y'";
```

Where X is the prefix you want to use and Y being the sotre id you want to do this for.

Comment: Good point! This makes your code more shippable and reapply the changes within another environment. You still use raw queries in your code though, maybe it would be better to used the Magento models and collections to do the same.